# how to separate two array?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I'm creating a music to show notes on Treble and Bass but came to think the `staffArray` and `staffArray2` is true for a given situation.

Such as `staffArray` and `staffArray2` has a value of "1","1","1","1" and "2",2",2",2",2",2"...

When one of the function will identify if the i=0 is 1 then draw note:

```
if(staffArray[i] == "1" && typeArray[i]=="half" && stemArray[i]=="down") {
drawHalfDown(child,"-","-");     //child is the sprite name
}
```

Now will draw a note on a staff 2, the above staffArray is still valid and cause the note on staff 2 to be error, how do I rectify these array?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand all of what you are trying to do, but your error is probably caused by a typo in your if-clause: The single `&` is a bitwise, not a logical boolean operator and evaluates to a very different result.  If you're interested, you can find out about bitwise AND [here](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/operators.html#bitwise_AND). 
Your code should be:

```
if(staffArray[i] == "1" && typeArray[i]=="half" && stemArray[i]=="down") {
    drawHalfDown(child,"-","-");   
}
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add another & in my post, my code have been update and previously, have done many commercial projects, the music application was very unique.

Comment: Decided to duplicate the functions which solve the issue. Question closed.